# How can get Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1") Hexadecimal code?

Tags: encoding, character-encoding, sms, sms-gateway

I need to send a SMS via HTTP Post with some special characters like "caiò"

So, with my code , I try to convert my string in ISO-8859-1.

basically, if my string is converted in ISO-8859-1, and  the method Uri.EscapeDataString() is invoked on it, in place of "ò" I should have "F2" Hexadecimal code. But I get %C3%A0 , that is the Hexadecimal code for UTF8 encoding.

```
     Encoding iso = Encoding.etEncoding("ISO-8859-1");   

                string StringBody = iso.GetString(iso.GetBytes(Body));

   UrlParameter += "&data=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(StringBody);
```

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do here, but iso.GetString (decoding) and iso.GetBytes (encoding) cancel each other out.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Do you know , how can I take special characters ISO-8859-1 Hexadecimal code?

Comment: I might not be able to, but it would probably help getting better answers if you augment your question with examples of what you would be getting in Body (which I'm assuming is a regular C# (Unicode) string) and what UrlParameter should then look like.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, encoding a string and decoding it right back is just a pointless round-trip at best and causes data loss at worst.

`Uri.EscapeDataString` always [correctly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Current_standard) encodes as UTF-8. Any server should support this.

You can try [`HttpUtility.UrlEncode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h10z5byc.aspx) which accepts an encoding parameter:

```
Encoding iso = Encoding.getEncoding("ISO-8859-1");  
UrlParameter += "&data=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Body, iso);
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe the text API shall have Unicode support... proper encoding of text message at your end is important... However text message API shall support that aswell... API Supporting the UNICODE messaging will do the Job....

Here is what i did in PHP... I am not much in to coding for other language sorry about that

```
if ($cmd['method'] == 'POST') {
$opts['http']['method'] = 'POST';
$opts['http']['header'] .= "\r\nContent-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"; 
$opts['http']['content'] = $post_data;
}

$context = stream_context_create($opts);
```

I used [Innovative Text API Gateway](http://www.innovativetxt.com)  which provided Unicode support and allowed me to send Chinese, Japani, Arabic and other language messages.